# Weird collision bug in Unity 2d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

[Github Repository (Scripts folder, has all code in .cs files)](https://github.com/gioragutt/GameOfThrowsUnity/tree/master/GameOfThrows/Assets/Scripts)

I have this weird collision bug in unity, here's a gif of it:

[image: GIF]

Recreating: In the gif, for example, I press both <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> until the velocity normalizes, and I get some why stuck in a block.

I've had this before with my own collision algorithm when I did the game in XNA, hoped this would not happen in Unity.

This is the player script `PlayerMovement`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        Back,
        Left,
        Front,
        Right,
        Idle = -1
    }

    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Public Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Maximum speed of the player (Accelerated to over a period of time)
        /// </summary>
        public float speed;

        /// <summary>
        /// Debug UI.Text element
        /// </summary>
        public Text debugText;

        #endregion

        #region Constants

        /// <summary>
        /// Constant for decaying the velocity on updates
        /// </summary>
        private const float VELOCITY_DECAY_FACTOR = 0.85f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constant to convert normal speed sizes to fit the scale
        /// Of UnityEngine.Vector2
        /// </summary>
        private const float HUMAN_TO_VECTOR_SCALE_FACTOR = 850f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constant to set the base speed of the player animation
        /// </summary>
        private const float BASE_ANIM_SPEED = 0.7f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constant to slightly reduce the animation speed after 
        /// It is multiplied by the velocity of the player
        /// </summary>
        private const float POST_VELOCITY_MULTIPLICATION_ANIM_SPEED_FACTOR = 0.5f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constant to set the animation speed
        /// </summary>
        private const float ANIM_SPEED_MODIFIER = BASE_ANIM_SPEED * POST_VELOCITY_MULTIPLICATION_ANIM_SPEED_FACTOR;

        /// <summary>
        /// Epsilon before velocity zerofication
        /// </summary>
        private const float VELOCITY_EPSILON = 0.1f;

        #endregion

        #region Private Members

        private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
        private Vector2 velocity;
        private Animator animator;
        private Directions dir = Directions.Idle;

        #endregion

        #region Game Loop Methods

        private void Awake()
        {
            animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            UpdateVelocity(horizontal, vertical);
            UpdateAnimation(horizontal, vertical);
            UpdateMovment();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Animation Methods

        private void UpdateAnimation(float horizontal, float vertical)
        {
            UpdateAnimation(new Vector2(horizontal, vertical));
        }

        private void UpdateAnimation(Vector2 input)
        {
            Directions direction;

            if (input.y > 0)
                direction = Directions.Back;
            else if (input.y < 0)
                direction = Directions.Front;
            else if (input.x > 0)
                direction = Directions.Right;
            else if (input.x < 0)
                direction = Directions.Left;
            else
                direction = Directions.Idle;

            SetDirection(direction);
        }

        private void SetDirection(Directions value)
        {
            animator.SetInteger("Direction", (int)value);
            dir = value;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Movement Methods

        private void UpdateMovment()
        {
            rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            KinematicsDebugPrints();
            ApplySpeedDecay();
        }

        private string GetDebugPrintDetails()
        {
            return string.Format("HOR : {0}\nVER : {1}\nDIR : {2}:{3}\nX : {4}\nY : {5}",
                velocity.x,
                velocity.y,
                animator.GetInteger("Direction").ToString().PadLeft(2),
                (Directions)animator.GetInteger("Direction"),
                rb2D.position.x,
                rb2D.position.y);
        }

        private void KinematicsDebugPrints()
        {
            var details = GetDebugPrintDetails();
            debugText.text = details;
            Debug.Log(details);
        }

        private void UpdateVelocity(float horizontal, float vertical)
        {
            if (vertical != 0)
                velocity.y += Mathf.Sign(vertical) * speed / HUMAN_TO_VECTOR_SCALE_FACTOR;
            if (horizontal != 0)
                velocity.x += Mathf.Sign(horizontal) * speed / HUMAN_TO_VECTOR_SCALE_FACTOR;
            animator.speed = ANIM_SPEED_MODIFIER * velocity.MaxOfXandY() ;
        }

        private void ApplySpeedDecay()
        {
            if (velocity == Vector2.zero) return;

            velocity *= VELOCITY_DECAY_FACTOR;
            velocity = velocity.ZerofiyTinyValues(0.1f);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is the player object currently:

[image: player]

And this is the wall object (prefab is the same for all walls except for the image:

[image: WALL]

This is a gif of my other bug:

[image: bug two]

This is how the collision box and circles look like:

[image: new collision boxes]

And this are the details from the inspector

[image: new inspector]

---

So after speaking with Hamza Hasan, he helped me to turn all the outer wall box colliders into four continues colliders, one per side(top, bottom, left, right).

The code for it is on the [`BoardManager`](https://github.com/gioragutt/GameOfThrowsUnity/blob/master/GameOfThrows/Assets/Scripts/BoardManager.cs) script in the `CreateWallsColliders` method.

This is how the scene currently looks like in the scene editor:

[image: new scene editor]

Comment: Did you know your `UpdateMovment` function is missing an 'e'?
But anyways, I'd try breaking it down to the basics of the movement to isolate the problem. Comment out the calls to the animation and velocity, and see if the glitch still occurs. If it works fine, add in the velocity call, and then the animation call. 

My guess is that something might be happening in the velocity call that's causing it to zero out when it reaches the maximum velocity.

Comment: What velocity call are you talking about? and thanks for pointing out my typo

Comment: I meant the `UpdateVelocity` function.

Comment: Is changing the player collider to an ellipse an option?

Comment: Why do that? Do you have a reason to?

Comment: If the wall is made of tiles, I suspect box2d-s collision engine would sometimes collide with the inner sides of the walls.

Comment: I also don't have ellipse collider, only a circle one

Comment: I thing somehow we should get rid of the sharp edges of the box collider. Using an octagonal poligon collider (which looks like a rectangle with it corners cut off) might help as well

Comment: I used `Polygon Collider 2D` and it still has a couple of joints in the polygon which gets stuck the same way.

Comment: The unity tutorial for platformer games suggest using circle colliders. Give me a minute, unity is still installing

Comment: Look, leave comments here, it's 1:20am and I need some sleep. Thanks for trying to help though, really appreciated!

Comment: @hege_hegedus yes, problem is what exactly you said. it collide with the inner-up side of walls. this problem can be solved by avoiding using sharp edged colliders. but there is no 2d collider like ellipse collider in unity. only circle and box collider

Comment: I'm afraid the best you can do is to imitate a capsule shaped collider, using two circles at the head and the legs, and a slightly thinner box for the body, between those circles.

Comment: I take back it's the inner side of the wall, it's more likely the bottom (outer) side of the next tile of wall

Comment: You're right hege, it always seems to stuck me when I'm aligned with the bottom side of the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all move your input code from `FixedUpdate` to `Update` otherwise it leads app to laggy behaviour. Second thing is you can do this by creating [PhysicsMaterial2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html) with `Friction = 0` and `Bounciness = 0` and attach it to the player as well as walls collider in `Material`. Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

Here is an alternative solution for you, instead of using 1 box collider per block, use only 1 collider per side. 4 Colliders in total.

Here is the code, you can add it to your `BoardManager` class. And call it in at the end of `SetUpScene` method, you can further modify it.

```
void CreateWallsColliders ()
        {
            GameObject colliders = new GameObject ("Colliders");
            colliders.transform.position = Vector3.zero;

            GameObject leftCollider = new GameObject ("LeftCollider");
            leftCollider.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
            BoxCollider2D bcLeftCollider = leftCollider.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
            leftCollider.transform.parent = colliders.transform;

            GameObject rightCollider = new GameObject ("RightCollider");
            rightCollider.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
            BoxCollider2D bcRightCollider = rightCollider.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
            rightCollider.transform.parent = colliders.transform;

            GameObject topCollider = new GameObject ("TopCollider");
            topCollider.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
            BoxCollider2D bcTopCollider = topCollider.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
            topCollider.transform.parent = colliders.transform;

            GameObject bottomCollider = new GameObject ("BottomCollider");
            bottomCollider.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
            BoxCollider2D bcBottomCollider = bottomCollider.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
            bottomCollider.transform.parent = colliders.transform;

            // Assuming 15 x 15 tiles. Make it dynamic if you need.
            // Assuming -1 and 15 are the limits on both sides

            int rows = 15;
            int cols = 15;

            int lowerLimit = -1;
            int upperLimit = 15;

            leftCollider.transform.position = new Vector3 (lowerLimit, rows / 2);
            leftCollider.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, cols, 1);

            rightCollider.transform.position = new Vector3 (upperLimit, rows / 2);
            rightCollider.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, cols, 1);

            topCollider.transform.position = new Vector3 (cols / 2, upperLimit);
            topCollider.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (rows, 1, 1);

            bottomCollider.transform.position = new Vector3 (cols / 2, lowerLimit);
            bottomCollider.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (rows, 1, 1);
        }
```

Comment: Regarding `FixedUpdate`, I was answered before in previous posts that all physics related operations should be executed in `FixedUpdate` and not `Update`. Second of all, I'm gonna check that soon, and third of all, thank you for the answer!

Comment: I did mention about taking Inputs un `Update` only :)

Comment: Ohh, so only the `UpdateInput` method... Ok ok I'll check that out as well. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: And colliders suggestion of **hege_hegedus** is right, set colliders according to his first suggestion and then apply my answer.... It will definitely solve your problem :)

Comment: Added new bug description, I did what you suggested and moved the input to update, and changed the collision boxes to what hege suggested.

Comment: Did you apply material to all colliders or players? I can see it only in one. You should apply it in walls collider too

Comment: I did apply the material to the walls

Comment: And remaining two circle colliders of player??

Comment: My git seems to have reset a lot of my stuff because my push got a bit messed up. I'm changing stuff to the way they were, and it made me notice that I didn't put the materials on the circular collisions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99010/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-giora-guttsait).

Comment: set player's rigidbody's **Interpolate** -> **Extrapolate** and **Collision Detection** -> **Continuous**. :))

Comment: @HamzaHasan you might add that to your answer

Answer (score 7):

The phenomenon you experience is caused by the rectangular collider of your character colliding with the bottom edge of the next tile of wall. This 'bug' is very common in physics engines. It is caused by some computation errors, and should be expected. This is why most games have bounding ellipses for characters, as ellipses don't have corners or edges.

One way to get rid of this sudden stop is to ensure that **all contiguous tiles of wall are represented as a single collider** (a rectangle or a polygon). This needs a separate logic that creates the colliders from the obstacles after loading the level, and the colliders must be updated after every change in the level (opening doors, etc...)

A much simpler way to solve the problem is to change the collider of the character. If the rectangular shape of your character is not essential, I recommend you to use a collider of the following shape:

[image: capsule shaped collider]

Or if the rectangular shape is essential, you can extend the corners with circles:

[image]

Comment: I've tried the first way, with the two big circles, and there seems to be this thing, that when I do the same thing, it sometimes glitches a bit to the sides, like wobbles a big to the left and two the right for a moment... it's not always like that. I'll try to make a proper gif and show it here

Comment: Did you try what Hamza Hasan suggested? A gif would be appreciated.

Comment: The gif isn't very clear tho... You can maybe try and see that it zigs a bit from the left to the right and back, and you can see the original bug is not entirely gone :\

Comment: I have cloned your repository and the collider is still a rect

Comment: I have not yet updated all of it, just the scripts. I'll update the rest in a sec

Comment: Maybe create a branch for it in git ;)

Comment: I don't mind just throwing it all in master. It's not that I've made so much actual changes... for now I'll have everything in master :) i'm pushing it all now

Comment: The push is taking a while :P I'll write when it ends :O

Comment: Apparently the push got messed up yesterday and everything got deleted, so I've updated everything back to the way it was and uploaded to the git normally.

Comment: Make the center rect thinner, like `width=0.8`, and the character will no longer get stuck. About the little jumps, I think that happens when update and updatefixed gets out of sync