# Continuous moving ball stuck at some time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, velocity, unity3d-2dtools

I am working on 2d game where monster with circular body moving continuously on screen. I have established grid which get filled by player movement so overall area for monster gets reduced based on player cover its area.

Using following code monster is moving continuously but at some point it get stuck at some corner and stop moving.

```
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
 private bool isStartMoving;
 private Vector3 direction;
 private float sFactor = 10.0f;
 private float localScaleX, localScaleY;

 //
 public float cSpeed = 5.0f;

 void Start ()
 {
     InitializeValues ();
 }

 private void InitializeValues ()
 {
     localScaleX = transform.localScale.x;
     localScaleY = transform.localScale.y;
     float xDirection = Random.Range (0, 2) * 2 - 1;
     float yDirection = Random.Range (0, 2) * 2 - 1;
     direction = new Vector3 (xDirection * cSpeed, yDirection * cSpeed, 0f);

     rigidbody2D.velocity = direction;
     isStartMoving = true;
 }

 void FixedUpdate ()
 {
     if (!isStartMoving) 
         return;

     // current velocity
     Vector3 cVel = rigidbody2D.velocity;
     if (cVel == Vector3.zero) 
         return;

     // normalized vector * constant speed
     Vector3 tVel = cVel.normalized * cSpeed;
     if (tVel.x > 0) 
         tVel.x = cSpeed;
     else 
         tVel.x = -cSpeed;

     if (tVel.y > 0) 
         tVel.y = cSpeed;
     else 
         tVel.y = -cSpeed;

     rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.Lerp (cVel, tVel, Time.deltaTime * sFactor);
 }
```

}

I have assign physics material in following manner.

[image]

Something like this type of situation happening with me.

[image]

You clearly see in image bottom right corner monster is sleeping though continuous movement code is running. Please give me suggestion to improve this.

From above code I removed following code :

```
if (cVel == Vector3.zero)
          return;
```

Then also my monster get stuck at corner position.Why monster is sleeping at corner position that I can't able to understand!!!

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457613/weird-collision-bug-in-unity-2d-game/34460923#34460923) may help you

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can't see any effect of the `FixedUpdate()` function at all. What do you need it for? The monster will keep moving as long as its `Rigidbody` has a velocity set, which you already did in `Start()`. Also, it should never lose speed because you set friction to 0. Try removing `FixedUpdate()`.

Also, what you mustn't do in `FixedUpdate()` is work with `Time.deltaTime`. `Time.deltaTime` gives you the time since last frame. `FixedUpdate()` however may be called several times per frame, or even not at all. You must use `Time.fixedTime` whenever you are calculating time based stuff in `FixedUpdate()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because multiple monster is moving on screen. So it might be possible monster collide with each other and put a break on monster's velocity. I want same speed of monster all time in game. Applying constant velocity because only this reason. One more point, monsters don't have open ground to move then often need to pass through pipe share way.